# Changing the default location of onedrive on my ubuntu 17.10 pc

Tags: sync

I've just downloaded 17.10 and installed onedrive via the terminal but i would like for onedrive to be stored by default on my 1TB HDD not my 250GB SSD even when i sync it.

At the moment it automatically syncs it to my Home dir in on the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux Mint.

- Install onedrive: `sudo apt install onedrive`
- Create symbolic or soft link

  ```
           physical location       link location
  ln -s /location_real_OneDrive /home/your_user/OneDrive
  ```
- Execute: `onedrive`
- Configure OneDrive

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of items to comment on here:

1. Installing via 'apt install onedrive' will install the wrong application version ... do not do this. If using Ubuntu 18.x and below, compile from source, if using Ubuntu 19.x and above use the Ubuntu PPA.
2. Whilst you can change the 'sync_dir' using a symbolic link, you can configure the sync_dir parameter within the application configuration to point at the correct location. See https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md#sync_dir for more details.